# PHP: using an environment variable as a reference to a local constant

Tags: php

My code:

```
const T = 'test';
const B = 'boat';

$const_var = getenv('FOO');
```

In my VirtualHost section, I have:

```
SetEnv FOO T
```

Obviously $const_var evaluates to the character `T`.

What I want to do is to be able to use the value of local const T, by using the value of the environment variable as a reference. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [`constant()`](http://php.net/constant) function to resolve the value indirectly.

```
 print constant($_ENV["FOO"]);
```

Or in your case `$const_var` as parameter.

Comment: I'm trying to understand this better. Can `constant($_ENV["FOO"])` be the same as `$_ENV["FOO"]`. And also, would I be able to serve up the same variable as `$_SERVER["FOO"]`?

Comment: All it does really is to look up the string identifier in PHPs constant hashtable. So writing `constant("E_NOTICE")` evaluates to the same value as a literal `E_NOTICE` in your code. And the string param can be an environment variable. -- `$_ENV` and `$_SERVER` can be identical on some setups, on many configs `$_ENV` is unfilled though, which is why OP is using `getenv()`.

Comment: To use $_ENV, it has to be enabled in the server config files. System admins avoid it because it takes up a lot of memory/resources, and if this is a heavy traffic site, it could add up pretty quickly. By setting the environment variable in the specific virtual host section of the web server, you're only loading that single variable in memory, and you always know it will be available and immune from other global server settings.

Comment: @EastsideDeveloper For convenience you could alias it. In the simplest of cases `$_ENV = "getenv";` which then requires curly string expression syntax like `print "..{$_ENV('FOO')}..";`. Or a callable object wrapper w/ `ArrayAccess` doing the same (that's what I use).